# Python (spyder) skipping lines of code in a function?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, dna-sequence

I am doing a project from a bioinformatics course. 
For the project we receive multiple DNA strings and an integer k. The task of the project is to find a K-mer motif that minimizes the sum of hamming distance between the motif and each DNA string.

I wrote a function MedianString(seqLines,k) for the task. In the function,  initial values for firstly assigned to a few variables, and then a for loop was included. When I call the function, python seems to skip all the lines before the loop and runs directly what's within the loop. I tried to search online for possible cause of the problem and found some similar discussions, but none of them seemed to be applicable for my case. I am pretty lost...

the lines that python skipped:

```
print('BBBBBBBBBBBBBB')
distance = 100000000000000000000000000000000
print('distance=')
print(distance)
Median = []
pattern = []
sumHD = 0
```

the lines that were run:

```
for i in range (0, 4**k-1):
    pattern = NumberToPattern(i,k)
    print('this is pattern')
    print (pattern)
    sumHD = sumOfMinHD(pattern,seqLines)
    print('sumHD=',type(sumHD))
    print(sumHD)
    print('distance=',type(distance))
    print(distance)
    if distance > sumHD:
        print('distance>sumOfMinHD')
        distance = sumOfMinHD(pattern,seqLines)
        Median = pattern
        print('distance=')
        print(distance)
    else:
        print('distance is <=sumOfMinHD')
```

the full code(pseudocode credit: Finding Hidden Messages in DNA (Bioinformatics I) by University of California San Diego):

```
#Code Challenge: Implement MedianString.
#Input: An integer k, followed by a collection of strings Dna.
#Output: A k-mer Pattern that minimizes d(Pattern, Dna) among all possible choices of k-mers. 
#(If there are multiple such strings Pattern, then you may return any one.)
 #the concept of the code:
 #MedianString(Dna, k)
 #   distance ← ∞
 #   for each k-mer Pattern from AA…AA to TT…TT
 #       if distance > d(Pattern, Dna)
 #            distance ← d(Pattern, Dna)
 #            Median ← Pattern
 #   return Median

with open(r'D:\Users\moonc\Desktop\python_exercises_for_bioimformatics_I\MedianStringSampleInput.txt','r') as seqFile :
    DataSet = seqFile.read().splitlines()
    print ('this is Dataset')
    print (DataSet)
    seqLines = DataSet [1:]
    print ('this is seqLines')
    print (seqLines)
    print (len(seqLines))
    k = int(DataSet[0])
    print ('this is k')
    print (k)

#NumberToPattern
def NumberToPattern(number, k):
    pattern = []
    for i in range (0,k):
        if number // (4**(k-1-i)) == 0:
            pattern.append ("A")
        elif number // (4**(k-1-i)) == 1:
            pattern.append ("C")
        elif number // (4**(k-1-i)) == 2:
            pattern.append ("G")
        elif number // (4**(k-1-i)) == 3:
            pattern.append ("T")

    number = number % (4**(k-1-i))

    intToString = map(str, pattern)  
    patternString = "".join(intToString)

    return patternString

#Hamming Distance Problem: Compute the Hamming distance between two strings.
#   Input: Two strings of equal length.
#   Output: The Hamming distance between these strings.

def HammingDistance(p,q):
    HD = 0
    for i in range(0,len(p)):
        if p[i] != q [i]:
           HD = HD+1

    return HD


#minHDandMotif(Pattern, Text) is the minimum Hamming distance between Pattern and any k-mer in Text

def minHDandMotif(Pattern,String):
    HD = float('inf')
    motif = []
    for i in range (0,len(String)-len(Pattern)+1):
        if HammingDistance(Pattern,String[i:i+len(Pattern)]) < HD:
            HD = HammingDistance(Pattern,String[i:i+len(Pattern)])
            motif = String[i:i+len(Pattern)]
       # print (motif)
    print ('this is minHD and Motif')
    print ([HD,motif])
    return [HD,motif]


#sumOfMinHD(Pattern, Dna) as the sum of distances between Pattern and all strings in Dna
#Dna is a collection of strings of the same length

def sumOfMinHD(Pattern,seqLines):
    sumHD = 0
    print(seqLines)
    for i in range (0,len(seqLines)-1):
        minHD = minHDandMotif(Pattern,seqLines[i])[0]
        sumHD = sumHD + minHD
    print ('this is sum Of MinHD')
    print (sumHD)
    return sumHD
######################
def MedianString(seqLines,k):
    print('BBBBBBBBBBBBBB')
    distance = 100000000000000000000000000000000
    print('distance=')
    print(distance)
    Median = []
    pattern = []
    sumHD = 0
    for i in range (0, 4**k-1):
        pattern = NumberToPattern(i,k)
        print('this is pattern')
        print (pattern)
        sumHD = sumOfMinHD(pattern,seqLines)
        print('sumHD=',type(sumHD))
        print(sumHD)
        print('distance=',type(distance))
        print(distance)
        if distance > sumHD:
            print('distance>sumOfMinHD')
            distance = sumOfMinHD(pattern,seqLines)
            Median = pattern
            print('distance=')
            print(distance)
        else:
            print('distance is <=sumOfMinHD')
    return Median
####################  
Median = MedianString(seqLines,k)
print ('this is MedianString')
print (Median)
```

the console of the last recursion of the loop in MedianString(seqLines,k):

```
this is pattern
TTG
['AAATTGACGCAT', 'GACGACCACGTT', 'CGTCAGCGCCTG', 'GCTGAGCACCGG', 'AGTACGGGACAG']
this is minHD and Motif
[0, 'TTG']
this is minHD and Motif
[2, 'ACG']
this is minHD and Motif
[1, 'CTG']
this is minHD and Motif
[1, 'CTG']
this is sum Of MinHD
4
sumHD= <class 'int'>
4
distance= <class 'int'>
2
distance is <=sumOfMinHD
this is MedianString
ACC
```

Comment: Be very careful with your code indentation! At the moment your indentation is inconsistent, and the code you’ve posted consequently won’t run at all. This might very well be related to the issue you’re observing.

Comment: I'm noticing some broken indentation in your code, but some of it should prevent the code from running at all, so it may be introduced here. Could you ensure the indentation shown here matches what is in the actual script?

Comment: Konrad Rudolph and Christoph Burschka thanks a lot for the reminder! This is the first time I post at stackoverflow. The indentation was off when I pasted the code. I will fix them.

Comment: The indentation in the post is now exactly the same as my code

Comment: Seems the code should work fine. My best guess is that you're running so many iterations that your first print statements are getting pushed out of the console results. Try running a single loop for MedianString() by indenting the return line once more. See if you can observe your beginning print statements.